# Would the humans ban the immigration of the colonial hobbit?

Tags: society, near-future

In a world with technological level of the near future, where humans use robots for specialized tasks but still need human labor, large conglomerate has genetically designed a hobbit like creature to colonize an extreme [planet](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/55624/how-to-design-hobbit-to-colonize-extreme-planet).
This type of genetic projects are forbidden but in this circumstance the government approved since the humans couldn't live on that planet.

However colonists found them useful as a source of cheap labor and spread them throughout the colonies. Hobbits are hired for jobs that require little training (routine maintenance, cooks, waiters, attendants, ushers, cleaners etc) usually several hobbits work under human boss whose job is to organize the work .

In the colonies there's lack of humans, as transport is very expensive so most of the colonists are highly skilled professionals (doctors, engineers, pilots...) hobbits don't threaten their jobs. However on the home planet situation is the reverse.

The hobbits threaten jobs and negotiating power of the low skill humans, if the restaurant owner has to pay 2000 for a human, hobbit costs 200.
It makes economical sense for owner to replace expensive humans with cheap hobbits, with keeping just those that handle jobs that hobbits can't do, like head waitress to deal with troublesome customers, or chef to organize kitchen of hobbit cooks, porters & dishwashers.

Would the humans push the government to ban the hobbits from migrating to the main world?

The characteristics of the hobbit are as below:

- Height of 120 cm, resembles a 9 old child
- Lifespan of 20 years, sexual maturity at 4, fully grown at 6
- IQ similar to 10 year old, learns fast simple things
- Very efficient metabolism needs little food
- Quite an individualistic [character](https://joejarvis.me/2016/08/31/why-cats-are-individualists-and-dogs-are-collectivists/) closer to cats then to dogs

Comment: So you're asking whether Humans who are not highly skilled professionals would be phased out by hobbits, thus would the humans ban them?

Comment: Yes,  humans can't compete on price with hobbits with routine jobs that don't require much thinking, but they could vote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No unless you bring millions of them in short time, otherwise voters don't think in such a long term in the future.

In the beginning there would be few of them so they would be a novelty, few hobbits here and there drawing crowds, oh look at the hobbit host it's so cute. When their numbers go up economy will adjust.

In the long run low skills humans will be worse off, but by then robots would take over.

Answer (score 3):

## Probably not

So you say

> Hobbits are hired for jobs that require little training (routine maintenance, cooks, waiters, attendants, ushers, cleaners etc)

And

> IQ similar to 10 year old, learns fast simple things

While I don't agree that cooking requires little training, say your 'Hobbits' picked up cooking as a job. Your 'Hobbits' have the IQ of a year old, learns simple tasks fast. This doesn't mean they will be able to cook well nor master the art of cooking. Your average 10 year old child would not be able to cook a medium-well steak with crisp calamari and salad. And I would personally prefer to have my food cooked by real cook and not a 'Hobbit'. Can you imagine what would happen if the 'Hobbit' learnt something like 'sugar makes food taste better', **proceeds to empty entire canister of sugar onto Steak**.

My point is that your 'Hobbits' probably won't be able to do their jobs as well as some humans and if they can't do their jobs as well as other humans then there won't be a major phasing out of humans from their jobs due to an inherent demand for higher quality products and work.

And if your 'Hobbits' can't kick humans out of a job then there won't be as much a demand to ban them from the Human's homeworld.

Comment: Maybe  some fancy 5 star restaurants would prefer human cooks but to say that 10 year old can't learn to cook  food served in 90% of the restaurants watch the skills of this guys https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gRMidGqGTd4  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XafhuC-PIqk  and even for something chef-y https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c6trN2S5qJ4

Comment: I did say average, there are always exceptions.